# Diferença entre casting e promotion

Tags: java, terminologia, cast

O que é *casting*? O que é *promotion*? Qual a diferença básica entre esses tipos de conversão em Java?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A **promoção** é a elevação dos tipos numéricos existentes na linguagem para um tipo que pode representar uma maior grandeza. As regras do que pode ser promovido estão especificadas na linguagem e indicam sempre que um tipo primitivo<sup>*</sup> de menor capacidade numérica pode ser usado em um lugar onde será necessário um tipo com maior capacidade. A promoção nunca provoca perda de dados. Ela é feita implicitamente pelo compilador.

O ***casting*** é a mudança de um tipo para outro de forma explícita através do operador de *casting* (o nome do tipo entre parênteses). Pode haver uma mudança de representação do valor ou não, e nesta conversão pode haver perda de dados. Um erro em tempo de execução ocorrerá se não for possível realizar a conversão ou o compilador pode detectar antes a impossibilidade da operação. O *casting* pode ou não mudar a representação do valor, o que não corre em tipos por referência.

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) para mais informações.

Note que isto é válido apenas para Java. Outras linguagens possuem suas próprias regras e terminologia. Não sei como fica com o advento de `struct`s no Java.

<sup>*</sup>Essa ideia de primitivo vai ficar complicada quando Java tiver dados básicos assim que não são primitivos (e terá em breve). E quero ver como eles vão lidar com *casting* já que eles decidiram não ter sobrecarga de operador, vão mudar de ideia ou será mais uma coisa capenga?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: gostaria de entender quando se falar o exemplo de cast, quando diz que pode haver perda de informação. Porem todos os exemplo que utilizo o cast eu não percebo essa perda de informação. Poderia me ajudar entender melhor esse conceito?