# Pegar atributo id de objeto selecionado no JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Tenho uma tabela no BD com Colunas Id, Placa N° e Furação na placa.

Eu gostaria de mostrar no `JComboBox` a concatenação de "Placa N° + Furação".

Exemplo:

> Placa 10 - 113,00 mm

Mas quando um item do combobox for selecionado pelo usuário, capturar o ID correspondente do objeto `Placa`. Estou fazendo no Netbeans e MySQL.

Segue o método que pesquisa no banco(DAO):

```
public ArrayList<Placa> ObterTabelaPlaca() {
    conectar();
    ArrayList<Placa> placa = new ArrayList<Placa>();
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM cadastroplaca ORDER BY CAST(furoPL AS DECIMAL(5,2))";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Placa pl = new Placa();
            pl.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            pl.setCodPlaca(rs.getInt("codigoPL"));
            pl.setFuracao(rs.getDouble("furoPL"));
            placa.add(pl);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro " + e.getMessage());

    }
    return placa;
}
```

A classe Placa(Modelo):

```
public class Placa {
    int codPlaca, qtdMoldePlaca, id;
    double furacao;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    String notaPlaca;

    public int getCodPlaca() {
        return codPlaca;
    }

    public void setCodPlaca(int codPlaca) {
        this.codPlaca = codPlaca;
    }

    public int getQtdMoldePlaca() {
        return qtdMoldePlaca;
    }

    public void setQtdMoldePlaca(int qtdMoldePlaca) {
        this.qtdMoldePlaca = qtdMoldePlaca;
    }

    public double getFuracao() {
        return furacao;
    }

    public void setFuracao(double furacao) {
        this.furacao = furacao;
    }

    public String getNotaPlaca() {
        return notaPlaca;
    }

    public void setNotaPlaca(String notaPlaca) {
        this.notaPlaca = notaPlaca;
    }


}
```

O método que preenche o componente(Do controller):

```
 public void MostraComboPlaca() throws SQLException{
        CadastroDAO dao = new CadastroDAO();        
        ArrayList<Placa> listaplaca = dao.ObterTabelaPlaca();
        DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        placaCilindrico.setModel(new ComboModelTipo(listaplaca));
        for(int i=0;i<listaplaca.size();i++){ 
        placaCombo.addItem(String.valueOf(formato.format(listaplaca.get(i).getFuracao()).replace('.', ','))+" - PL "+listaplaca.get(i).getCodPlaca());
        }
 }
```

Não consigo concluir o raciocínio da parte do Controle, para pegar o id do item selecionado.

---

Eu armazeno os detalhes da tabela numa `ArrayList` com a DAO acima.

```
placa.add(pl);
```

E populo o ComboBox(Valores Furação) usando o Modelo abaixo:

```
public void MostraComboPlaca() throws SQLException{
    CadastroDAO dao = new CadastroDAO();        
    ArrayList<Placa> listaplaca = dao.ObterTabelaPlaca();
    placaCombo.setModel(new ComboModelTipo(listaplaca));

 }
```

Uso esta classe como ComboBoxModel:

```
public class ComboModelTipo extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel {

private ArrayList<Placa> lista;
private Placa selected;

public ComboModelTipo(ArrayList<Placa> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
    return this.lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return this.lista.get(index).getFuracao();
}

@Override
public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
    this.selected = (Placa) anItem;
}

@Override
public Object getSelectedItem() {
    return this.selected;
}

public Integer getIdObjetoSelecionado() {
return selected.getId();
}
}
```

Após essas etapas meu ComboBox é populado, mas quando clico em algum valor, ocorre o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você criou um ComboModel proprio para a classe placa?

Comment: diegofm, procurei fazer por ajuda deste tópico...
http://respostas.guj.com.br/1430-buscar-id-do-campo-selecionado-no-combobox-resolvido

public class ComboModelTipo extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel {

Comment: Adicione um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel simular o problema, Leia mais [**aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/28595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A causa da exceção

O método [`getElementAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html#getElementAt-int-) deve retornar o objeto selecionado na lista, não seu atributo, como você está fazendo. Altere o método abaixo da seguinte forma:

```
@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return this.lista.get(index);
}
```

---

## Alterando a exibição dos itens no ComboModel

Para exibir a informação no combo sem afetar o tipo de objeto é utilizando um [**`ListCellRenderer`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html):

```
public class PlacaComboRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value instanceof Placa) {
            Placa placa = (Placa) value;
            DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
            String text = String.valueOf(formato.format(placa.getFuracao()).replace('.', ','))+" - PL "+ placa.getCodPlaca();
            setText(text);
        } else if(value == null) {
            setText("Selecione uma placa:");
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Neste caso, eu optei por utilizar a classe `DefaultListCellRenderer` porque ela não só implementa a interface `ListCellRenderer` como também traz outras funcionalidades afim de evitar termos que implementar um ListCellRenderer completo do zero.

Para aplicar, basta fazer isso:

```
 public void MostraComboPlaca() throws SQLException{
        CadastroDAO dao = new CadastroDAO();        
        ArrayList<Placa> listaplaca = dao.ObterTabelaPlaca();
        DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        placaCilindrico.setModel(new ComboModelTipo(listaplaca));
        //precisa ser exatamente após o ComboBoxModel ser aplicado
        placaCombo.setRenderer(new PlacaComboRenderer());
}
```

E para capturar itens deste `JComboBox`, basta pegar o item selecionado, fazer o *[casting](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102348/28595)* para seu objeto `Placa` e chamar o método que retorna o ID:

```
Placa placaSelecionada = (Placa)seuCombo.getSelectedItem();
int id = placaSelecionada.getId();
```

Não precisa criar um método no `ComboBoxModel`(no caso o `getIdObjetoSelecionado()`) para resgatar o id do objeto selecionado, uma vez que você já sabe que o `getSelectedItem` retornará um objeto tipo `Placa`, a solução acima já cobre isso.

Comment: Ok diegofm, agora está funcionando legal!

Comment: @RafB-- que bom, qualquer coisa, só avisar :)

Comment: @RafB-- em perguntas futuras, é interessante você adicionar o erro em forma de texto ao invés de foto, porque em texto facilita a busca pelo problema, caso outros tenham um parecido com o seu.

Comment: Só uma curiosidade: Como posso exibir o "Selecione" no Combobox? Ates dele popular o combo. Penso que teria que ser algo dentro do PlacaComboRenderer.

Comment: @RafB-- veja a edição na classe `PlacaComboRenderer `, foi a forma mais simplista e "bruta" que achei, sem ter que desvirtuar a duvida dessa pergunta. Após algo ser selecionado, a mensagem desaparece e não volta mais até que a aplicação seja reaberta. Se quiser algo mais elaborado que isso para exibir uma opção padrão, ai terá que criar uma nova pergunta com um **[mcve]** do combo para teste.