# Retornar um resultado de SQL

Tags: java

Estou com uma consulta em sql que está me retornando de uma forma errada.

Ele esta retornando assim:

```
[Cidade.Cidade@1d8b06a, Cidade.Cidade@251a5c, Cidade.Cidade@15ec3c1
```

e eu gostaria que retornasse assim

```
Acrelândia
Assis Brasil
```

Segue o código do metodo:

Classe Cidade:

```
package Cidade;

public class Cidade {

    private String nom_cidade;
    private String estado;

    public String getNom_cidade() {
        return nom_cidade;
    }
    public void setNom_cidade(String nom_cidade) {
        this.nom_cidade = nom_cidade;
    }
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String toString(){
            return this.nom_cidade;
    }
}
```

Classe CidadeDao

```
public class CidEstDao extends GenericDao {

    public List<Cidade> getCidadeByEstado(String nom_cidade) throws Exception {
        String select = "SELECT nom_cidade FROM cidade WHERE estado = ?";
        Cidade cidade = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(select);
        List<Cidade> cidades = new ArrayList<Cidade>(); 
        stmt.setString(1, nom_cidade);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            cidade = new Cidade();
            cidade.setNom_cidade(rs.getString("nom_cidade"));
            cidades.add(cidade);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return cidades;
    }
}
```

Classe CidadeEstController

```
public class CidEstController {

    public List<Cidade> buscaCidadePorEstado (String nom_cidade) throws Exception{
        CidEstDao dao = new CidEstDao();
        return  dao.getCidadeByEstado(nom_cidade);
    }
}
```

Classe principal

```
private List<Cidade> cidadePorEstado() throws Exception {
        CidEstController cc = new CidEstController();
        try {
            //List<Cidade> c = cc.buscaCidadePorEstado(uf);
             //List<Cidade> listaCidades = new ArrayList<>();
             //listaCidades = cc.buscaCidadePorEstado (uf);
           return cc.buscaCidadePorEstado (uf);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente!n" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Contato não localizdo ou não existe!n" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Comment: Outra relacionada:[Dúvidas sobre o método toString() da classe Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10893/28595)

Comment: A edição só reforça que esta pergunta é duplicata de qualquer uma das duas linkadas, da uma olhada nas duas perguntas e suas respostas.

Comment: Esta pode te ajudar a [popular o JCombobox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204149/28595)

Comment: Desculpe mas o toString ele compara dois valores, eu nao quero isso e add itens a combobox eu ja sei.
Essa consulta ela busca as cidades por estado e para retornar todas as cidades eu coloquei List<cidade> porem quando adiciono os valores numa box ou faço um println fica com aqueles valores e eu quero saber como alterar o metodo para que fora dele ao adicionar a uma box ele saia com os nomes das cidades.

Comment: O `toString()` não compara nada, ele apenas exibe uma representação criada pelo java do objeto. Os 3 links que postei resolvem seu problema. O terceiro eu ainda explico como fazer exibir corretamente num combobox.

Comment: Esta pode te ajudar, caso não queira sobrescrever `toString()`, mas utilizar um renderer para o combo: [Pegar atributo id de objeto selecionado no JComboBox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168458/28595)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema da seguinte forma

```
try {
            for (Cidade a : cidadePorEstado()) 
                boxCidade.addItem(String.valueOf(a));

                    ;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CadCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema da pergunta. Sua duvida não tem nada a ver com o proposto pela resposta.

Comment: Na verdade te, sim, eu mantive a classe principal como estava, e para exibir ao inves de usar o toString que me retornava assim: 

[Cidade.Cidade@1d8b06a, Cidade.Cidade@251a5c, Cidade.Cidade@15ec3c1

Eu usei esse metodo try, ele retorna os nomes das cidades CORRETAMENTE dentro da BOX conforme o estado que eu escolho.
Se quiser posso mandar o projeto pra vc por completo e voce mesmo pode analisar.
Obrigado por tudo.

Comment: Só tem 2 formas de resolver isso, que é reescrevendo o tostring, como eu te mostrei, e como você adicionou na sua classe cidade(código da pergunta) ou fazendo um combomodel. Remova o método tostring da sua classe cidadee tenta usar esse codigo da sua resposta pra voce ver. Não vai funcionar, é o tostring que muda a exibição, como eu mostrei na resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O que está explicado nos links que postei de outras perguntas é que para exibir algo mais personalizado de um objeto ao inves de `nomeDaClasse@hashcode`, que é a exibição padrão criada pelo java, você precisa sobrescrever o método `toString()` da classe, no seu caso, Cidade.

Como você não deu nenhuma informação desta classe, vou sugerir um exemplo às cegas:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return this.nome;//aqui você troca NOME pela 
                    //variavel que representa o nome da cidade na sua classe
}
```

Adicione este método na classe `Cidade` e problema resolvido.

Comment: Eu acredito que fiz como comentou mas não consegui, faz pouco tempo que to trabalhando com consulta sql e to apanhando.
alterei a postagem e pus as classes se puder me ajudar, eu realmente agradeço to perdido.

Comment: @DiegoGomesDias adicionou o método na classe Cidade como eu sugeri? Se sim, o problema está resolvido.

Comment: Adicionei até postei ele no titulo para ver, mas nao deu certo.

Comment: @DiegoGomesDias então o problema não está nos códigos que você apresentou na pergunta. Ai você precisa apresentar um "[mcve]" do seu código para que seja possivel testa-lo.

Comment: Coloquei apenas o metodo de cada classe referente a consulta da cidade, classe cidade, classeDao, classeController e a classe principal.
Como faço pra que o retorno nao seja hashcode, vc pode dar uma analisada no que eu fiz, por favor.

Comment: @DiegoGomesDias eu ja fiz isso, não tem outra solução a sugerir sem você apresentar um código testavel. Veja se por acaso não ta importando classe cidade de outro pacote ou de outro projeto. Fora isso, não tem mais como te ajudar com as informações passadas.

Comment: @DiegoGomesDias A resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda da resposta :)