# ArrayList versus List

Tags: c#, .net, array, estrutura-de-dados, lista

Qual o motivo de no C# devemos dar preferência de usar o `List` ao invés de `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Porque `List` é genérica e [`ArrayList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) não é. O tipo do dado de `ArrayList` é um `object`, ou seja pode por qualquer coisa nela. Em linguagens estáticas isto não é adequado, você perde a segurança de tipos, não pode mais confiar no conteúdo da lista. Já [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) determina qual é o tipo que pode colocar nela, então todo o código é confiável que só terá elementos daquele tipo específico e de tipos derivados dele que obviamente são compatíveis com este tipo. O próprio compilador consegue garantir a segurança de tipos.

Não é só segurança, é performance também. Evita-se assim o [*casting*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102345/101) e o [*boxing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55147/101) (tipos por valor só podem ser colocado por referência em um `ArrayList`, isto é péssimo.

O `ArrayList` existe porque C# 1 não tinha genéricos ainda. A solução quando precisava da segurança de tipos era criar uma nova estrutura parecida com o `ArrayList`, mas que internamente tinha um tipo específico, assim daria a segurança e performance, porém fazer uma para cada tipo que precisasse era praticamente inviável.

Ainda é possível usar `List<object>` se desejar aceitar qualquer tipo de objeto na lista, mas raramente isto é o desejado. Também é possível usar [`List<dynamic>`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101) onde o compilador nem verifica o acesso ao objeto, que tem vantagens e desvantagens. Quando usa o `List<object>` toda vez que pegar o elemento só pode acessar os membros do tipo [`Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), a não ser que faça um *cast*  para o tipo que deseja. Dá trabalho, o código fica confuso e verboso, é lento, e pode gerar erros facilmente se não tomar muito cuidado.

Exemplo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var array = new ArrayList() { 1, "texto" };
        var total = 0;
        foreach (var item in array) {
            //total += item; //se tirar o comentário dá erro quando tentar somar a string
        }
        //array[1].Contains("t"); //mesmo sendo string não pode acessar Contains() porque o tipo é object
        ((string)array[1]).Contains("t");
        var list = new List<int>() { 1, /*"texto"); //<-- Error at compile process //ddaria erro aqui*/ };
        total = 0;
        foreach (var item in list) total += item;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QzXWcm). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mauniV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ArrayListXList.cs).

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` é uma classe genérica. Ela suporta armazenar valores de um tipo específico sem a necessidade de forçar de ou para `object`.

`ArrayList` simplesmente armazena referencias de objeto. Como uma coleção genérica, `List<T>` implementa a `IEnumerable<T>` interface genérica e pode ser usada facilmente no `LINQ` (sem precisar de `Cast` ou `OfType`).

`ArrayList` pertence aos dias em que C# não tinha genéricos. É depreciado em favor de `List<T>`. Você não deve usar `ArrayList` em um novo código que alveja .NET> = 2.0, a menos que tenha que se conectar a uma API antiga que o use.

referência: [stackoverflow.com/a/2309699/4190610](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2309699/4190610)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309699/4190610